# How to prevent further execution in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am iterating through a table as

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function(event){
    if($(this).hasClass('class1')){
       $(this).removeClass('class1');
       $(this).addClass('class2');
       event.stopPropagation();
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

But this does not stop the propagation.

Comment: Only event handlers get an `event` object passed to them. Iterating over a list of nodes doesn't have anything to do with event handling. Please explain what you mean by "propagation" in this case. It almost looks like you haven't read the [documentation of `.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (which clearly shows that the first argument passed to the callback is the index of the element).

Comment: Even if this *did* get an `event`, stopping propagation has *nothing* to with terminating the loop. That isn't what "event propagation" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no event here.

If you are trying to stop iterating, you can `return false;`:

```
$('#table1 tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('class1')){
       $(this).removeClass('class1');
       $(this).addClass('class2');
       return false;
    }
});
```

This is effectively the same as calling `break;` in a `for` loop.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524895/how-to-prevent-further-execution-in-jquery#comment36085562_23524895

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Because those are for preventing propagation of an event. There's no event here.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Because you don't know what they do. They "work" just fine, but there is no event, and no event propagation to stop here.

Comment: i frankly speaking never used i use to do return false in events as well

Comment: @EhsanSajjad You can put `return false;` in any function. That doesn't mean that you can replace that line with `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation()` in any function...